# Erro popular dropdown PHP com array

Tags: php, array, dropdown

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte função que me retorna os dados necessários para popular o meu dropdown:

```
    function listaRedes($conexao){
    $dados = array();

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT DISTINCT rede FROM evolucao_originacao");
    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        array_push($dados, $valores);
    }
    return $dados;
};
```

E no meu dropdown, estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
 <?php $redesBanco = listaRedes($conexão); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="dropdown-parceria">
                <option value="0">---SELECIONE---</option>
                <?php 
                    while($redesBanco){
                        echo "<option value='".$redesBanco."'>".$redesBanco."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Porém na hora que ele popula o meu dropdown, o resultado é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando voce faz o while você ainda esta iterando sob arrays, tente ver o que possui dentro do array com `var_dump($redesBanco)`,

Comment: @RafaelAcioly o array está com todos os dados que busquei do banco.

Comment: O `var_dump` é para vermos a estrutura do seu `array`.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach para percorrer o array:

```
<?php $redesBanco = listaRedes($conexão); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="dropdown-parceria">
                    <option value="0">---SELECIONE---</option>
                    <?php 
                        foreach ($redesBanco as $chave){
                            echo "<option value='".$chave[0]."'>".$chave[1]."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente colocar $redesBanco[0]. Pois você esta tentando dar um echo em um array, é recomendado você dar uma var_dump para ver a estrutura para escrever por exemplo, `<?php echo "<a href='".$redesBanco['link']."'>".$redesBanco['acesse']."</a>"; ?>`
Mas tambem pode ser feito da primeira maneira, informando o indice com o numero $redesBanco[0].
No caso do seu exemplo deveria ser feito de uma forma tipo essa...:

```
<?php $redesBanco = listaRedes($conexão); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="dropdown-parceria">
            <option value="0">---SELECIONE---</option>
            <?php 
                while($redesBanco){
                    echo "<option value='".$redesBanco[0]."'>".$redesBanco[1]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma

Comment: não funcionou @localhost

Comment: da um var_dump($redesBanco); e coloca o resultado ai, para eu poder ajudar melhor, caso nao tenha conseguido